# What should be the sizes of the Images for supporting both iOS & Android in React-Native

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-ios

I am an iOS developer, recently I have started creating an APP in React-native.
In iOS we provide 3 types of images x, @2x & @3x for supporting all the devices. When coming to android according in some of the developer sites/blogs, I have seen they use many resolution image sizes like ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi and like..

**My Question is**

So, In react-native what sizes of images should i use so as it fits in both iOS & Android devices.

In my login screen the image size I have used is "640 X 1138" & "750X1334", but here in Android devices the image is being trimmed in top and bottom of the screens, in iOS devices it is good to go.

Comment: why don't you use SVG format, so you don't have to put multiple images in your project for each screen size.

Comment: @Amas: I don't have idea on SVG format images, will check them

Comment: just a brief explanation: `Unlike raster formats seen in JPG, GIF, and PNG, an SVG image remains crisp and clear at any resolution or size.`

Answer (score 0):

You can use it separately by `platform`.

For images in the `Android` assets folder, use the `asset:/` scheme:

```js
<Image source={{ uri: 'asset:/app_icon.png' }} style={{ width: 40, height: 40 }} />
```

```js
var icon = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? require('./my-icon-active.png') : require('asset:/my-icon-inactive.png');
<Image source={icon} />;
```